# Why isn't my MacBook Pro detecting 2 out of 3 of my monitors?

Tags: display, dock, screen, hdmi, displayport

I'm having an issue extending 2/3 of my displays on my MacBook Pro. I have two 24inch Lenovo monitors, one 27inch Samsung monitor, one Lenovo docking station and my MacBook Pro.

My three monitors all display the same output as an extension to my MacBook Pro display but I can't use them as individual extensions. I'm wondering if this is a compatibility issue. I've tried to detect the monitors manually but no joy.

Here's a more detailed list of the monitors:

**Left monitor**: 24-inch Lenovo monitor with a straight HDMI connection to dock.

**Middle monitor**: 27-inch Samsung curved monitor with HDMI to Display Port connection to dock.

**Right monitor**: 24-inch Lenovo monitor with HDMI to Display Port connection to dock.

**MacBook Pro details**:
Model Name:   MacBook Pro
Model Identifier: MacBookPro16,3
Processor Name:   Quad-Core Intel Core i5
Processor Speed:  1.4 GHz
Number of Processors: 1
Total Number of Cores:    4
L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB
L3 Cache: 6 MB
Hyper-Threading Technology:   Enabled
Memory:   8 GB

And here's an image of what I see in the Display settings... as you can see it's missing two monitors:

[image: Screenshot of Display settings]

Comment: I'd be looking at the spec of the dock.

Comment: The dock is a lenovo thinkpad universal usb-c dock :)

Comment: Ahh, just found this, does anybody know if there's a work around?

"The dock itself will work if you only need a single display, no drivers needed (you can connect two displays, but they'll just mirror because the Windows uses MST for dual displays and Macs don't support it).  If you want dual displays, you need another dock.  The least expensive option is the Thunderbolt 3 Mini Dock from OWC.  I have used TB3 docks from Elgato and Brydge (Stone Pro) for dual displays."

Comment: what exact MacBook do you have?

Comment: Model Name: MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier: MacBookPro16,3
  Processor Name: Quad-Core Intel Core i5
  Processor Speed: 1.4 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores: 4
  L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
  L3 Cache: 6 MB
  Hyper-Threading Technology: Enabled
  Memory: 8 GB

Comment: By my count, you have 4 displays. There is the builtin display, two 24 inch Lenovo monitors and one 27 inch Samsung monitor. Both [Apple](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP818?locale=en_US) and [Intel](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/191067/intel-core-i58257u-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-90-ghz.html) state in their specifications the maximum displays is 3. I fail to understand how 4 extended displays is possible. I do not think you can increase the number of extended displays by adding a dock.

Comment: I will close my MacBook so in actual fact I'm only using 3. The point being that it's not picking up 2 of the monitors